# python regular expression to extract the last bracket

Tags: python, regex

My input is `(0,0)-(1.5,1.5)-(3.0,4.5)-(4.5,6.0)-(6.0,7.5)-(9.0,10.5)-(12.57,100.356)`
I want a regular expression to extract the two float in the last bracket: `12.57, 100.356`,  i tried

```
str_path_finder = re.compile(r'.*\-(d+\.d+,d+\.d+)')

rst = str_path_finder.search("(0,0)-(1.5,1.5)-(3.0,4.5)-(4.5,6.0)-(6.0,7.5)-(9.0,10.5)-(12.57,100.356)")
```

but rst is None.

Could

Comment: `d+` matches one or more `d` letters. Also, why regex? `text.split('-')[-1].strip('()').split(',')` [works](https://ideone.com/XhqtUo).

Answer (score 1):

You can write the pattern like this, and then take the group 1 value:

```
.*-\((\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)\)
```

- `.*` Match the whole line
- `-\(` Match `-(`
- `(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match the desired digits pattern (note to write `\d+` as `d+` matches 1 or more times a `d` char)
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Upu68T/1)

```
import re

s = "(0,0)-(1.5,1.5)-(3.0,4.5)-(4.5,6.0)-(6.0,7.5)-(9.0,10.5)-(12.57,100.356)"
pattern = r'.*-\((\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)\)'
m = re.match(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
12.57,100.356
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the parentheses, as they're otherwise regex metacharacters. Also, you can just anchor the regex to the end of the string with `$`:

```
>>> str_path_finder = re.compile(r'\([0-9.]+,[0-9.]+\)$')
>>> rst = str_path_finder.search("(0,0)-(1.5,1.5)-(3.0,4.5)-(4.5,6.0)-(6.0,7.5)-(9.0,10.5)-(12.57,100.356)")
<re.Match object; span=(57, 72), match='(12.57,100.356)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '(0,0)-(1.5,1.5)-(3.0,4.5)-(4.5,6.0)-(6.0,7.5)-(9.0,10.5)-(12.57,100.356)'
a, b = map(float, s[1:-1].split(')-(')[-1].split(','))
print(a, b)
```

prints

```
12.57, 100.356
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this function

```
def SearchTwoFloatNumbers(str_path):
    # convert str_path to array
    path_array = []
    for path in str_path.split("-"):
        path_array.append((float(path[1:-1].split(',')[0]),float(path[1:-1].split(',')[1])))

    # check if the two number in path are float 
    rst = []
    for index,path in enumerate(path_array):
        if (not int(path[0]) == float(path[0]) and not int(path[1]) == float(path[1])):
            rst.append(path)

    return rst




print(SearchTwoFloatNumbers("(0,0)-(1.5,1.5)-(3.0,4.5)-(4.5,6.0)-(6.0,7.5)-(9.0,10.5)-(12.57,100.356)"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just append a . and the *$* character, at the end.

```
(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+).$
```